# how to format like this?

Tags: formatting, thesis

[image]

On the title page I have got the blue strip but not able to put a logo image at top left and address box in top right.

I have reached so far using

```
\documentclass[PhD,synopsis]{iitmdiss}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{t1enc}

%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref} % hyperlinks for references.
\usepackage{amsmath} % easier math formulae, align, subequations \ldots
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}


\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
  \color{blue}\rule{.10\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}
  
%

\title{Title of the thesis}

\author{}

\date{March 2021}
\department{}


\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please do show us the code you've come up with so far.

Comment: \usepackage{times}
\usepackage{t1enc}

%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref} % hyperlinks for references.
\usepackage{amsmath} % easier math formulae, align, subequations \ldots
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}


\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
  \color{blue}\rule{.10\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}
  
%

\title{Title of this thesis}

\begin{document}

Comment: Your document class ist empty: `\documentclass[PhD,synopsis]{}`. Which one are you using?

Comment: More to the point, the title page appears to be peculiar to the document class you are using.

Comment: Have added the class.

Comment: @k94 something on similar lines in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx} % remove this line in your document
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shape=rectangle,fill=blue!70!black,minimum height=\paperheight,anchor=south west, minimum width=12em]at($(current page.south west)+(0cm,0cm)$) (redline) {};
        
        \node at($(redline)+(6cm,9cm)$) (logo) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}};
        
        \node[align=left] at($(logo)+(10cm,0cm)$) (adr) {address\\
        line 1\\line 2};
        
        \draw [line width=2pt]($(redline.east)+(0cm,7cm)$)-|($(current page.east)+(0cm,7cm)$);
        
        \node [draw]at($(redline.east)!0.5!(current page.east)+(0cm,5cm)$) (logo){\Large \textbf{Some Title Text}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```